# mod_security rule 981203 false positive

Tags: apache, mod-security, mod-security2

I just installed mod_security on my Apache2 web server.

I activated all of the `base_rules/` from OWASP CRS.

I found a false positive by looking inside of `/var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log`.

The target URL is:

> /mobile//index.cfm?gclid=Cj0KEQjw_qW9BRCcv-Xc5Jn-26gBEiQAM-iJhcydtemGoKm4rCJ7gbEgz5qL-MXF0tMh5BkaxVPZPYwaAvhW8P8HAQ

The error log is:

> Message: Warning. Pattern match
>   "([\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\+\=\{\}\[\]\|\:\;\"\'\\xc2\xb4\\xe2\x80\x99\\xe2\x80\x98\`\<\>].*?){4,}"
>   at ARGS:gclid. [file
>   "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"]
>   [line "159"] [id "981173"] [rev "2"] [msg "Restricted SQL Character
>   Anomaly Detection Alert - Total # of special characters exceeded"]
>   [data "Matched Data: - found within ARGS:gclid:
>   Cj0KEQjw_qW9BRCcv-Xc5Jn-26gBEiQAM-iJhcydtemGoKm4rCJ7gbEgz5qL-MXF0tMh5BkaxVPZPYwaAvhW8P8HAQ"]
>   [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.8"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "8"] [tag
>   "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION"] Message: Warning. Operator LT
>   matched 5 at TX:inbound_anomaly_score. [file
>   "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_60_correlation.conf"]
>   [line "33"] [id "981203"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score (Total Inbound
>   Score: 3, SQLi=1, XSS=0): Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection
>   Alert - Total # of special characters exceeded"]

The message is self-explaining but... that is not a malicious URL, for my website.

How can I 'whitelist' this kind of URLs (e.g. containing gclid parameter) instead of completely disabling rule 981203?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add this config after you've defined the other rules:

```
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981203 !ARGS:'gclid'
```

However I see a lot of false positives with this rule so often turn it off completely. The OWASP CRS is prone to over alerting and requires a lot of tuning.

See this post for other suggested common rule tweaks:
[Modsecurity: Excessive false positives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989273/modsecurity-excessive-false-positives/34027786#34027786)

Comment: Thanks a lot Barry for your answer, [I was able to solve a similar issue using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285328/mod-security-rule-981172-false-positive/55285329#55285329)