# mod_security rule 981172 false positive

Tags: apache, mod-security, grav

The mod_security configuration in Apache, on the CWP7.admin, generates a `403 access denied` error when running Grav CMS:

> [Thu Mar 21 15:40:47.967502 2019] [:error] [pid 21727:tid 140715786946304] [client 186.67.206.59:57900] [client 186.67.206.59] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "([\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\-\\+\\=\\{\\}\\[\\]\\|\\:\\;\"\\'\\\xc2\xb4\\\xe2\x80\x99\\\xe2\x80\x98\\`\\<\\>].*?){8,}" at REQUEST_COOKIES:grav-tabs-state. [file "/usr/local/apache/modsecurity-owasp-old/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"] [line "157"] [id "981172"] [rev "2"] [msg "Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection Alert - Total # of special characters exceeded"] [data "Matched Data: \x22 found within REQUEST_COOKIES:grav-tabs-state: {\x22tab-content.options.advanced\x22:\x22data.content\x22,\x22tab-content.options\x22:\x22data.content\x22,\x22tab-content.options.advanced.blog\x22:\x22data.options\x22}"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION"] [hostname "xxxxxxxx.com"] [uri "/favicon.ico"] [unique_id "XJOwf0cQATwA6mgjE8O7AwAAANc"], referer: http://xxxxxxxx.com/

This error only happens when visiting the website a second time, making it very hard to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon inspecting the logs, I found the same pattern of errors for Grav CMS based sites generated by mod_security. [This answer by Barry Pollard guided my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858866/345605)

The error noted the mod_security rule blocking my request:

> /usr/local/apache/modsecurity-owasp-old/base_rules/**modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf**

the corresponding line

> [line "157"]

And its ID

> [id "981172"]

Using the advice from Barry , I added the following line after the rule:

```
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981172 !REQUEST_COOKIES:grav-tabs-state
```

In this case I'm asking `mod_security` to omit `REQUEST_COOKIES:grav-tabs-state` from the rule 981172. This solved the issue.

Thanks from the bottom of my heart to @barrypollard